# The best way to implement a docker container in C# with a timer

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, docker, timer

I'm considering using Docker and C# to rewrite an existing system.

The containers will work by scanning a SQL Server queue table for jobs that they can process and then perform the necessary updates for that job.

The queue will be scanned regularly using a Timer object.

The only way I can see to create a Docker process in Visual Studio is to create an ASP.Net Core project and enable Docker in the new project wizard.

I once used a Timer inside a RESTful server but I found that, if there were no HTTP requests for a while, IIS would unload the assemblies and the Timer would stop firing.

My questions are:

- Would the container run continuously or would it stop if there were
  no HTTP requests like IIS?
- Is an ASP.Net Core project the way to go for this type of container
  or is there a better way?

Comment: Containers *contain* software. They don't *do* anything. You start and stop them like VMs and they start running whatever you configured them to run. They have nothing to do with Visual Studio either - VS doesn't *create* containers. It only creates the files used by Docker to create and start containers. It's Docker that does the actual job.  You can write a console application and include it in a container if you want

Comment: Also, you should not be performing long-running tasks such as this from IIS; you've already found one possible side affect. Instead, please consider a Windows Service. Visual Studio includes a template with Start and Stop methods.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - That's what I was wondering.  I think that would be a better solution for me.

Comment: @Null511 - I realise that now.  I was just relaying my early experiences of using IIS.